# iCalendar data format: Create recurrent event that shifts to the previous workday if it falls on a holiday

Tags: icalendar

Is there a way to create a iCalendar ics file that uses a RRULE that repeats regularly but shifts the date to the last workday before that day if the day in question is a holiday?

For example, let's say the week starts on Monday and workdays are Monday to Friday. A RRULE for the second Tuesday of every month would shift it to Monday if Tuesday is a holiday, or to the Friday the week before if both Mon and Tue are holidays.

I guess the basic RRULE would be something like

```
RRULE:FREQ=MONTHLY;BYDAY=2TU
```

but how would the shifting be done? I know that there is the EXDATE property and I could probably feed all my holidays into it, but it seems to just drop the dates, not shift them.